# Bit run rundown

Tags: code-golf, sequence, binary, subsequence

Given an integer `n > 0`, output the length of the longest contiguous sequence of `0` or `1` in its binary representation.

**Examples**

- `6` is written `110` in binary; the longest sequence is `11`, so we
  should return `2`
- `16` → `10000` → `4`
- `893` → `1101111101` → `5`
- `1337371` → `101000110100000011011` → `6`
- `1` → `1` → `1`
- `9965546` → `100110000000111111101010` → `7`

Comment: [OEIS A043276](http://oeis.org/A043276)

Comment: Can we assume any bound of the size of the integer like 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: @xnor yes you can assume the int is 32 bits max

Answer (score 32):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>46</s> 45 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=1:`k`in bin(n^n/2)and-~f(n,k*10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#DYxBCoMwFAXX7SneJmgk0qbRpBHsUYqREAjqV8R1r57@xYOBN0xJ4xq2OQaQWkY9TMuUCXOmmr70eMlAsf2lms9GP2VJ@wkCG1ZB897eMBjjjNMMCt7bvu/scL8dZ6YLlXAR7QciVhDgDjgmZfkD)

#### How it works

By XORing **n** and **n/2** (dividing by **2** essentially chops off the last bit), we get a new integer **m** whose unset bits indicate matching adjacent bits in **n**.

For example, if **n = 1337371**, we have the following.

```
n    = 1337371 = 101000110100000011011₂
n/2  =  668685 =  10100011010000001101₂
m    = 1989654 = 111100101110000010110₂
```

This reduces the task to find the longest run of zeroes. Since the binary representation of a positive integer always begins with a **1**, we'll try  to find the longest **10*** string of digits that appears in the binary representation of **m**. This can be done recursively.

Initialize **k** as **1**. Every time **f** is executed, we first test if the decimal representation of **k** appears in the binary representation of **m**. If it does, we multiply **k** by **10** and call **f** again. If it doesn't, the code to the right of `and` isn't executed and we return *False*.

To do this, we first compute `bin(k)[3:]`. In our example, `bin(k)` returns `'0b111100101110000010110'`, and the `0b1` at the beginning is removed with `[3:]`.

Now, the `-~` before the recursive call increments *False*/**0** once for every time **f** is called recursively. Once **10{j}** (**1** followed by **j** repetitions of **0**) does not appear in the binary representation of **k**, the longest run of zeroes in **k** has length **j - 1**. Since **j - 1** consecutive zeroes in **k** indicate **j** matching adjacent bits in **n**, the desired result is **j**, which is what we obtain by incrementing *False*/**0** a total of **j** times.

Comment: This is really clever!

Comment: Wow, that's clever. Never could've thought of it.

Comment: Nice trick with the powers of 10, but don't they become longs with an L?

Comment: @xnor Eventually, but that's just a data type limitation. The C, JavaScript, and PHP answers also suffer from this.

Comment: This would be seriously unmaintainable if used in production. In short (ghehe) golf achieved, hole in one :)

Answer (score 17):

### Python 2, 46 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,r=1:max(r,n and f(n/2,1+~-n/2%2*r))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FYzBCsIwEAXP@hXvEprqFtmsGC3Uf4mEQMFuZfHgyV@v62GYOc3WpmdZHrVAySYel/KJRoqiFS3qKREfv4M7pIP1/dZWg2JWMOFCYEc8OZ0J15t4iWTJPO53L5v1jS7kiuGOUDsERKX/1kc/)

Extracts binary digits from `n` in reverse by repeatedly taking `n/2` and `n%2`. Tracks the length of the current run `r` of equal digits by resetting it to 0 if the last two digits are unequal, then adding 1.

The expression `~-n/2%2` is an indicator of whether the last two digits are equal, i.e. `n` is 0 or 3 modulo 4. Checking the last two digits together turned out shorten than remembering the previous digit.

Answer (score 14):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
b.¡€gM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@5@kd2jho6Y16b7//xsaG5sbmxsCAA)

**Explanation**

```
b       # convert to binary
 .¡     # split at difference
   €g   # map length on each
     M  # take max
```

Comment: HA! Finally! A use for `.¡`, I can stop forcing myself to try to use it.

Comment: @carusocomputing: Pretty sure I've used it in a couple of answers.

Answer (score 9):

### Mathematica, 38 bytes

```
Max[Length/@Split[#~IntegerDigits~2]]&
```

or

```
Max[Tr/@(1^Split[#~IntegerDigits~2])]&
```

Answer (score 9):

## Python, 53 bytes

```py
import re;lambda g:max(map(len,re.findall('1+|0+',bin(g))))
```

Anonymous lambda function.

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
BŒgL€Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@90dFK6z6OmNQ93Nvw/3A5k/P8fbaajYAjEFpbGQIaxsbmxuWEsAA)

#### How it works

```
BŒgL€Ṁ  Main link. Argument: n

B       Binary; convert n to base 2.
 Œg     Group adjacent, identical elements.
   L€   Map length over the groups.
     Ṁ  Take the maximum.
```

Answer (score 9):

### Ruby, <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```
->b{("%b%b"%[b,~b]).scan(/1+/).max.size}
```

Find longest sequence of '1' in b or its inverse.

Thanks to manatwork for saving 1 byte.

Comment: Not sure about other versions, but in 2.3.1 there is no need for the space between the `%b`'s.

Comment: You are right, negative binary numbers start with "..". Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

## Ruby, <s>51</s> <s>44</s> 43 bytes

Function solution.

@manatwork is made of magic

```
->s{('%b'%s).scan(/0+|1+/).map(&:size).max}
```

Comment: Does this check for consecutive identical digits or just consecutive `0`s?

Comment: Incorrect result for 893.

Comment: @orlp not anymore! :D

Comment: I would combine the 1st and 2nd solutions: `->s{s.to_s(2).scan(/0+|1+/).map(&:size).max}`.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 54 bytes

```
f=(n,r=0,l=1,d=2)=>n?f(n>>1,d^n&1?1:++r,r>l?r:l,n&1):l
```

A recursive solution with a lot of bit manipulation. `n` stores the input, `r` stores the length of the current run, `l` stores the length of the longest run, and `d` stores the previous digit.

#### Test snippet

```js
f=(n,r=0,l=1,d=2)=>n?f(n>>1,d^n&1?1:++r,r>l?r:l,n&1):l

for(var i of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,16,893,1337371]) console.log(`f(${i}): ${f(i)}`)
```

Comment: Same idea, but using more bit operations and exploiting the default conversion of undefined to 0. Feel free to borrow: `f=(x,b,n,m)=>x?f(x>>1,x&1,n=x&1^b||-~n,m>n?m:n):m`

Answer (score 7):

## Perl, 43 bytes

```perl
#!perl -p
\@a[$a+=$_-1+($_>>=1)&1||-$a]while$_;$_=@a
```

Counting the shebang as one, input is taken from stdin.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#@x/jkBitkqhtqxKva6itoRJvZ2drqKlmWFOjq5IYW56RmZOqEm@tEm/rkPj/v4Wl8X/dAgA)

Comment: Shebangs count as 0 bytes.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline [consensus on meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5637/4098) is that `#!perl` counts as zero, not `#!perl -p`.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline: The `-p` costs 1, on the assumption that your Perl command line would have an argument anyway (e.g. `-e` or `-M5.010`), so you can slip a `p` in just after one of the hyphens. The `#!perl` is free (although unnecessary).

Comment: Good to know.  .

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, 57 bytes

```py
a=lambda n:n and max((n&-n|~n&-~n).bit_length()-1,a(n/2))
```

A recursive solution. There might be a shorter form for the bit magic.

Answer (score 5):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 16 bytes

Seems like there's gotta be a shorter way to get the runs of same digit...

```
MX#*(TBa`1+|0+`)
```

Takes input as command-line argument. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@@8boaylEeKUmGCoXWOgnaD5//9/QzMA)

#### Explanation

```
     TBa          1st cmdline arg, To Binary
    (   `1+|0+`)  Find all matches of this regex
  #*              Map length operator to that list
MX                Get the maximum and autoprint it
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 36 bytes

```
{(.base(2)~~m:g/1+|0+/)».chars.max}
```

Explanation:

```
{                                 }   # a lambda
  .base(2)                            # convert the argument to base 2
          ~~m:g/     /                # regex match, with global matching turned on
                1+|0+                 # match one or more 1, or one or more 0
 (                    )».chars        # replace each match by its length
                              .max    # take the maximum number
```

[Try it online](https://glot.io/snippets/em52gi3o7f).

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 79 characters

```
maximum.map length.group.i
```

where

```
import Data.List
i 0=[]
i n=mod n 2:i(div n 2)
```

Or in ungolfed version:

```
import Data.List
pcg :: Int -> Int
pcg = maximum . map length . group . intToBin

intToBin :: Int -> [Int]
intToBin 0 = []
intToBin n = n `mod` 2 : intToBin (n `div` 2)
```

### Explanation:

`intToBin` converts an int to a list of binary digits (lsb first). `group` groups contiguous sequences, such that `[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]` becomes `[[1, 1],[0, 0, 0],[1]]`. `maximum . map length` calculates for each inner list its length and returns the length of the longest.

Edit: Thanks to @xnor and @Laikoni for saving bytes

Comment: `group` isn't in Prelude by default, you need to do `import Data.List` to use it.

Comment: Note that you can use guards in place of `let`: ``i n|(q,r)<-n`quotRem`2=r:i q``. See our [Haskell golf tips](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/tips-for-golfing-in-haskell). `quotRem` can be `divMod`. I think you can use `i 0=[]` as the base case.

Comment: Using `div` and `mod` directly is even shorter: `i n=mod n 2:i(div n 2)`.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
heSr8.B
```

Do run length encode on the binary string, then sort it  so that the longest runs come last, then take the first element (the length) of the last element (the longest run) of the list.

In pseudocode:

```python
'  S     ' sorted(
'   r8   '   run_length_encode(
'     .BQ'     bin(input()) ))  \
'he      '   [-1][0]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 21 bytes

```
[:>./#:#;.1~1,2~:/\#:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGulEG1lp6evbKVsrWdYZ6hjVGelH6NsxZWanJGvoKGjl6ZkoKlgpmBopmBhaaxgaGxsbmxu@P8/AA)

### Explanation

```
[:>./#:#;.1~1,2~:/\#:  Input: integer n
                   #:  Binary digits of n
              2   \    For each continuous subarray of 2 digits
               ~:/       Reduce it using not-equals
            1,         Prepend a 1 to those results
     #:                Binary digits of n
        ;.1~           Cut the binary digits at each location with a 1
       #                 Get the length of each cut
[:>./                  Reduce those lengths using maximum and return
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 31 bytes

```matlab
@(n)max(runlength(+dec2bin(n)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gkaeZm1ihUVSal5Oal16SoaGdkppslJSZB5TQ1PyfpmCrkJhXbM2VpmGmqaOQpmEIoSwsjSFcY2NzY3NDCFvzPwA)

#### Explanation

This is a translation of my MATL answer. My initial plan was a different approach, namely `@(n)max(diff(find(diff([0 +dec2bin(n) 0]))))`. But it turns out that Octave has a [`runlength`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/runlength.html) function (which I just found out about). By default it outputs only the array of run-lengths, so the desired result is the `max` of that array. The output of `dec2bin`, which is a char array (string) containing `'0'` and `'1'`, needs to be converted to a numeric array using `+`, because `runlength` expects numeric input.

Answer (score 3):

**MATLAB** 71 bytes

```
m=1;a=diff(int8(dec2bin(a)));while(any(a==0)),m=m+1;a=diff(a);end;m
```

This converts integer variable 'a' to a binary int8 array then counts the number of times the result has to be differentiated until there is no zero in the result.

I am new here. Is this sort of input and one-liner allowed by the PCG rules?

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! By default, only [functions or full programs](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/36398) (not code snippets) are accepted. In your case that means you need to input `a` with `a=input('');`. Also, some golfing advice: `~a` instead of `a==0`. Do you really need `int8`)?

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) / Unix utilities, <s>66</s> <s>65</s> 42 bytes

Thanks to @DigitalTrauma for significant improvements (23 bytes!).

```bash
dc<<<`dc -e2o?p|fold -1|uniq -c|sort -n`rp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@SbGNjk5CSrKCbapRvX1CTlp@ToqBrWFOal1mooJtcU5xfVKKgm5dQVPD/v6WlmampiRkA)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Thanks for the improvements, especially for including fold, which hasn't been in my usual arsenal.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash (+coreutils, +GNU grep), <del>33</del>, 32 bytes

EDITS:

- Minus 1 byte (removed quotes around *grep* expression)

**Golfed**

```
dc -e2o$1p|grep -Po 1+\|0+|wc -L
```

**Explained**

```
 #Convert to binary
 >dc -e2o893p
 1101111101

 #Place each continuous run of 1es or 0es on its own line
 >dc -e2o893p|grep -Po '1+|0+'
 11
 0
 11111
 0
 1

 #Output the length of the longest line
 >dc -e2o893p|grep -Po '1+|0+'|wc -L
 5
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@SrKCbapRvX1CTXpRaoKAbkK9gqB1TY6BdUw6U8fn/39LSzNTUxAwA)

Comment: AFAIK, grep forms neither part of bash nor coreutils, though is maintained and distributed by its [own](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git). Not sure about dc, but it used to be a standalone tool in the GNU world. The only one forming part of coreutils is wc.

Comment: @Moreaki, _grep_ is POSIX, so any shell-based answer implies that it is already available. _dc_ is not POSIX but is a standard part of almost every *Nix system around, so it is not normally mentioned as a separate dependency, too.

Comment: I reckon we're on two different trains of thoughts here: my point was not if grep was POSIX or not, my point was that the title of your submission to me indicated that one would need bash +coreutils to make your solution work, while this seems not the case. When I read it first, this information was confusing to me. If you try your solution on a macOS shipped bash shell, it won't work; and it does not matter if you installed coreutils or not; you'd need GNU grep to make it work.

Comment: @Moreaki, yep, I just imply the GNU system, when I say +coreutils, althrough that is not always the case. I've updated the title to be more precise.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `G`, 4 bytes

```
bøef
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQRyIsIiIsImLDuGVmIiwiIiwiODkzIl0=)

Abuses the `G` flag which returns the maximum value of the item on top of the stack.

```
b      # convert input to binary
  øef  # run_length_encoding and flatten 2D -> 1D
       # Implicitly take the largest value in the flattened array
```

Answer (score 3):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), <s>41</s> 38 bytes

```ruby
~:digits&2|:slice_when+:!=|:*&:+@|:max
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWN9XqrFIy0zNLitWMaqyKczKTU-PLM1LztK0UbWustNSstB1qrHITK6CqLQoU3KLNYrlAlCGUtrA0hgoYG5sbmxtCORDK0tLM1NTELBaif8ECCA0A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
$b@b:lotl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog#@6@S5JBklZNfkvP/v6GxsbmxueH/KAA)

#### Explanation

```
$b          List of binary digits of the input
  @b        Runs of consecutive identical digits in that list
    :lo     Order those runs by length
       tl   Output is the length of the last one
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 66 Bytes

```
x=>Math.max(...x.toString(2).split(/(0+|1+)/g).map(y=>y.leng‌​th))
```

Thanks to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) for the code.

#### Explanation

```
x.toString(2)
```

Convert number to binary string.

```
split(/(0+|1+)/g)
```

Split every different character (0 or 1) (this regex captures empty spaces but they can be ignored)

```
map(y=>y.length)
```

For each element of the array get its length and put it in the returned array.

```
...
```

Convert array to list of arguments ([1,2,3] -> 1,2,3)

```
Math.max()
```

Get the largest number out of the arguments.

Comment: By crediting [Value Ink](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52194/value-ink)'s [Ruby solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106659) for the inspiration, this can be transformed into `x=>x.toString(2).split(/(0+|1+)/g).map(y=>y.length).sort().pop()`. Or the same length: `x=>Math.max(...x.toString(2).split(/(0+|1+)/g).map(y=>y.length))`.

Comment: I think you may have to add a predicate to the sort function `sort((a,b)=>b-a)`. By default, the sort function places `10` in between `1` and `2`.

Comment: Or you could use Math.max, as manatwork suggested.

Comment: Wtf, but they're numbers. JS please.

Answer (score 2):

### R, <strike>45</strike> 34 bytes

```
max(rle(miscFuncs::bin(scan()))$l)
```

Fixed a silly misunderstanding thanks to @rturnbull and @plannapus.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but isn't the input supposed to be an integer, not a binary number? And we're looking for the maximum run of `0` or of `1`, not just `0`, right?

Comment: @plannapus I don't know honestly. Must have missed the spec completely. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

### C#, 106 bytes

```
n=>{int l=1,o=0,p=0;foreach(var c in System.Convert.ToString(n,2)){o=c!=p?1:o+1;l=o>l?o:l;p=c;}return l;};
```

Formatted version:

```
System.Func<int, int> f = n =>
{
    int l = 1, o = 0, p = 0;
    foreach (var c in System.Convert.ToString(n, 2))
    {
        o = c != p ? 1 : o + 1;

        l = o > l ? o : l;

        p = c;
    }

    return l;
};
```

And an alternative approach accessing the string by index at 118 bytes, with whitespace removed:

```
System.Func<int, int> f2 = n =>
{
    var s = System.Convert.ToString(n, 2);

    int l = 1, c = 1, i = 0;

    for (; i < s.Length - 1; )
    {
        c = s[i] == s[++i] ? c + 1 : 1;
        l = l < c ? c : l;
    }

    return l;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wonder](https://github.com/wonderlang/wonder), 27 bytes

```
max.map#len.mstr`0+|1+`g.bn
```

Usage:

```
(max.map#len.mstr`0+|1+`g.bn)123
```

Converts to binary, matches each sequence of 0's and 1's, gets the length of each match, and gets the maximum.

Comment: Does this convert the input to binary?

Comment: oooooh I missed that part. Quick fix :P

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 102 bytes

```
@set/a"n=%1/2,d=%1%%2,r=1+(%3+0)*!(0%2^d),l=%4-(%4-r>>5)
@if not %n%==0 %0 %n% %d% %r% %l%
@echo %l%
```

Port of @edc65's answer. `%2`..`%4` will be empty on the first call, so I have to write the expressions in such a way that they will still work. The most general case is `%3` which I had to write as `(%3+0)`. `%2` is easier, as it can only be `0` or `1`, which are the same in octal, so `0%2` works here. `%4` turned out to be even easier, as I only need to subtract from it. `(%4-r>>5)` is used to compare `l` with `r` as Batch's `set/a` doesn't have a comparison operator.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>78</s> <s>74</s> 73 bytes

```powershell
([regex]::Matches([convert]::ToString("$args",2),'0+|1+')|% Le*|sort)[-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@68RXZSanloRa2Xlm1iSnJFarBGdnJ9XllpUAhQKyQ8uKcrMS9dQUkksSi9W0jHS1FE30K4x1FbXrFFV8EnVqinOLyrRjNY1jP3//7@hsbG5sbkhAA)

Ugh those .Net methods.

This just uses a regex to find (and match) contiguous sequences of ones and zeroes, then it takes the `Length` property (with a new pattern I found that uses a little known parameter set of `ForEach-Object`, to save 1 byte) of the resulting match objects, sorts them, and outputs the last one (the largest).

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](http://dyalog.com/download-zone.htm), 22 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Anonymous function train

```apl
⌈/∘(≢¨⊢⊂⍨1,2≠/⊢)2⊥⍣¯1⊢
```

`⌈/∘(`... The maximum of the results of the following anonymous function-train...

`≢¨`  the tally of each

`⊢⊂⍨` partition of the argument, where the partitioning is determined by the ones in

`1,` one prepended to

`2≠/` the pairwise unequal of

`⊢` the argument

`)` applied to

`2⊥⍣¯1` from-base-2 applied negative one times (i.e. to-base-2, once) to

`⊢` the argument

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%u2308/%u2218%28%u2262%A8%u22A2%u2282%u23681%2C2%u2260/%u22A2%292%u22A5%u2363%AF1%u22A2%20%u22C4%20f%A8%206%2016%20893%201337371%201%209965546&run)

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 15 bytes

```
2o!q¢ c ml n gJ
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.3&code=Mm8hcaIgYyBtbCBuIGdK&input=ODkz) or [Verify all test cases at once](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.3&code=Tm1VezJvIXGiIGMgbWwgbiBnSn0gcVI=&input=MQo2CjE2Cjg5MwoxMzM3MzcxCjk5NjU1NDY=).

#### How it works

```
                 // Implicit: U = input integer, J = -1
2o               // Create the range [0...2), or [0,1].
  ! ¢            // Map each item Z in this range to U.s(2)
   q             //                                        .q(Z).
                 // This returns the runs of 1's and 0's in the binary
                 // representation of U, respectively.
      c          // Flatten into a single list.
        ml       // Map each item Z to Z.length.
           n gJ  // Sort the result and grab the item at index -1, or the last item.
                 // This returns the largest element in the list.
                 // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
▲mLgḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0Tbk@6Q93dP///x8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>20</s> 17 bytes

```
|//{y+x*y}\'~:\2\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqkZfv7pSu0KrsjZGvc4qxijmf5q6mYKhmYKFpbGCobGxubG5oYKhgqWlmampidl/AA)

- `2\` convert (implicit) input to base-2 representation
- `~:\` build a two-item list containing the above, and the above negated
- `{y+x*y}\'` calculate "runs" of 1's, e.g. transform (0 1 1 1 0 1) into (0 1 2 3 0 1)
- `|//` return the maximum element (present in either list)

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `G`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ḃġḷ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOCU4MyVDNCVBMSVFMSVCOCVCNyZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTk5NjU1NDYmZmxhZ3M9Rw==)

##### Explanation

```python
ḃġḷ  # Implicit input
ḃ    # Convert to binary
 ġ   # Group consecutive items
  ḷ  # Length of each group
     # Implicit output of maximum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 4 bytes

```
ƂĉŞ#
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpKuoVLsgqWlJWm6FsuPNR3pPDpPeUlxUnIxVGzBLjMuQzMuC0tjLkNjY3Njc0MuQy5LSzNTUxMziAoA)

```
ƂĉŞ#
Ƃ       Binary digits
 ĉ      Split into runs of equal digits
  Ş     Find the longest run
   #    Length
```

When there are multiple runs of maximum length, it will return the length multiple times. You can add the `-1` flag to return it only once.

Answer (score 1):

## J, 27 bytes

```
>./>#&.>((1,2~:/\[)<;.1])#:
```

A slightly different (and unfortunately longer) approach to [miles's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106662/737).

Usage:

```
    >./>#&.>((1,2~:/\[)<;.1])#:893
5
```

**Explanation**

```
>./>#&.>((1,2~:/\[)<;.1])#:
                         #: Convert to base 2
        (               )   A fork
                       ]    Previous result
         (1,2~:/\[)         Find where each new sequence begins
                   <;.1     Cut the string of integers based on where each sequence begins and box them
    #&.>                    Count under open - open each box and count the items in it
>./>                        Open all the boxes and find the maximum value
```

Comment: I don't think this is valid--it isn't a function and so is a snippet.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Okay, I'll look at it again later.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
BY'X>&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@@8UqR5hp/b/v6GxsbmxuSEA)

#### Explanation

```
B    % Implicitly input a number. Convert to array of binary digits 
Y'   % Run length-encoding. Gives an array of values and an array of run-lengths.
     % Only the latter is needed
X>   % Maximum of array of run-lengths
&    % Next function will use its secondary default input/output specification
     % Implicitly display, only the top of the stack, as per the secondary
     % default specification
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 82 bytes

```
<?=preg_match_all('!(.)\\1*!',decbin($argv[1]),$a);max(array_map('strlen',$a[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>74</s> 72 bytes

```haskell
x!0=[1]
x!n|m<-mod n 2,r<-m!div n 2=last(1:[1+r!!0|m==x]):r
maximum.(2!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#FYixDoIwFEV3v@I2caCxEkoFhNivcGw6NGGwia@QAtqBf8c6nJtzz5FYpY20p8TCTo8rTSMCahGzstF//ke/3bIWcjDyEhmrdtI6WT7Eg5wP0Ji39blGlFhe0xdnkJtR5E2eNiqLmnFwGCnQCsjMvVdZlOpUl2Pft01za@3xAw) Usage:

```haskell
Prelude> maximum.(2!) $ 1337371
6
```

Not as nice and clean as the other Haskell answer, but some bytes shorter. The function `(!)` directly builds a list of lengths of `0` or `1` sequences by using a second parameter `x` to indicate whether a `0` or a `1` has been seen in the recursive call. If `x` matches the current bit, the head of the list is incremented (the sequence continues), otherwise a new `1` is appended (a new sequence with current length 1 starts). After building the list, `maximum` returns the maximum of the list, ie. the length of the longest sequence.

---

Getting rid of the `x` parameter by placing it as first element in the list seems not to save anything: (75 bytes)

```haskell
f n|n<1=[2,1]|m<-mod n 2,x:r<-f$div n 2=m:last(1:[1+r!!0|m==x]):r
maximum.f
```

However maybe the `maximum` can be integrated in the function to save some more bytes ...

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 50 bytes

Assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

Half the code is just converting to binary =/

```
.+
$*
+`(1+)\1
${1}0
01
1
M!`0+|1+
0
1
O`1+
1+¶

1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@nzaWixaWdoGGorRljyKVSbVhrwGVgyGXI5auYYKBdY6jNZQDk@CcAGYbah7ZxcRn@/29paWZqamIGAA)

**Explanation**

```
.+
$*
+`(1+)\1
${1}0
01
1
```

This converts the input number to binary.

```
M!`0+|1+
```

Splits the binary into contiguous runs of `0` and `1`, separated by linefeeds.

```
0
1
```

Replace all `0`s with `1`s.

```
O`1+
```

Sort the runs. Since all the runs are now sequences of `1`s, it will order them by length, from shortest to longest.

```
1+¶
​
```

Replaces all sequences of 1's followed by a linefeed with nothing. This leaves only the last (longest) sequence behind.

```
1
```

Counts the number of `1`s and outputs it.

Answer (score 1):

### C, <s>81</s> 72 bytes

Implementing [Dennis' idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106670/64412), in C:

```
f(n){int m=0,l=0;for(n^=n<<1;n;n>>=1,l++)if(n&1)m=l>m?l:m,l=0;return m;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
f(n){
    int m=0, l=0;         // m: max found, l: current sequence length
    n^=n<<1;              // apply Dennis' XOR trick
    for (; n; n>>=1,l++)  // iterate each bits (shift right) until no more bits set, and inc current length
        if (n&1)          // if LSB bit set
            m=l>m?l:m,    // set m to max(m, current length)
            l=0;          // reset current length
    return m;
}
```

Codepad [here](http://codepad.org/lyTYadn7).

Comment: [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcxRCoJAEADQf08hQjGDG7mRgg6TF4kgtjaEmTEW@xLPvsn7f@H0CSHnCIbrZEup3DjhhuKcwB5stdHuzBcUtqMfleWmowzq/CC1p/RefslKpS3rczLAtfimPYpQHV53q1yEvu/a9tohUrHlPw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## **MATLAB, 59 bytes**

```
@(n)max(cellfun(@numel,regexp(dec2bin(n),'1+|0+','match')))
```

Uses a regexp to split into strings of 0's and 1's, then cellfun to get the number of elements in each match.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>61</s> 68 bytes

```php
<?=strlen(max(explode(0,strtr($s=decbin($argv[1]),10,"01")."0$s")));
```

takes input from command line argument.

- convert input to binary
- concat inverted binary + "0" + binary
- split by `0` -> array of "11" "1111" etc.
- get longest streak -> string of `1`s
- print string length

**<s>96</s> 85 bytes for arbitrary length input**: coubt the bits in a loop (PHP 7.1):

```php
for($d=2;$a=&$argv[1];$n*=$d==$b=$a[-1]%2,$d=$b,$a=bcdiv($a,2))++$n<$m?:$m=$n;echo$m;
```

**+3 bytes for older PHP**:

```php
for($d=2;$a=&$argv[1];$n*=$d==$b=bcmod($a,2),$d=$b,$a=bcdiv($a,2))++$n<$m?:$m=$n;echo$m;
```

or **<s>96</s> 81 bytes** (PHP 5.6 or later with gmplib)

```php
for($a=gmp_init($argv[1])*$d=2;$a>>=1;$n*=$d==$a%2,$d=$a%2)$m=max($m,++$n);echo$m;
```

manually counting the bits in a [GMP](http://php.net/gmp) number

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 28 bytes

```
¢q0 m@XlÃn gJ w¢q1 m@XlÃn gJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@39oUaGBQq5DRM7h5jyFdC@FcqCAIZLA//@WlmampiZmAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 73 bytes

```
def f(a:Int,b:Int=1):Int=Math.max(b,if(a==0)0 else f(a/2,1+ ~(-a)/2%2*b))
```

A port of the Python 2 answer by [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor). The binary string lambda version is 2 bytes longer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](http://dyalog.com/download-zone.htm), 19 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

[`{≢⍉↑⊂⍨2≠/2,2⊥⍣¯1⊢⍵}`](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%7B%u2262%u2349%u2191%u2282%u23682%u2260/2%2C2%u22A5%u2363%AF1%u22A2%u2375%7D%20%u22C4%20f%A8%206%2016%20893%201337371%201%209965546&run)

Answer (score 1):

## R, 38 bytes

```
max(rev(rle(intToBits(scan()))$l)[-1])
```

Usage:

```
> max(rev(rle(intToBits(scan()))$l)[-1])
1: 6
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] 2
> max(rev(rle(intToBits(scan()))$l)[-1])
1: 893
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] 5
> max(rev(rle(intToBits(scan()))$l)[-1])
1: 1337371
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] 6
> max(rev(rle(intToBits(scan()))$l)[-1])
1: 9965546
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] 7
```

Ended up being a bit peculiar because of the way `intToBits` works.
Here is an example of how it woks with `6`:

```
> intToBits(6)
 [1] 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[24] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> rle(intToBits(6))
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:3] 1 2 29
  values : raw [1:3] 00 01 00
> rle(intToBits(6))$l
[1]  1  2 29
> rev(rle(intToBits(6))$l)[-1]
[1] 2 1
> max(rev(rle(intToBits(6))$l)[-1])
[1] 2
```

From the help file for `?intToBits`:

> `intToBits` returns a raw vector of 32 times the length of an integer vector with entries 0 or 1. (Non-integral numeric values are truncated to integers.) [...] the unpacking is least-significant bit first.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¤ò¦ mÊñ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=pPKmIG3K8Q&input=OTk2NTU0Ng)

```
¤ò¦ mÊñ     :Implicit input of integer
¤           :To binary string
 ò          :Partition on
  ¦         :  Inequality
    m       :Map
     Ê      :  Length
      ñ     :Sort
            :Implicit output of last element
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `G`, 23 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 2.875 bytes

```
bĠ@
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJHPSIsIiIsImLEoEAiLCIiLCI4OTMiXQ==)

Two can play at the G flag, binary-group-lengths game.

Quite literally ports Thunno 2, using newer features (`@`) than the existing vyxal answer.

Answer (score 1):

## x86-64 machine code, 24 bytes

Standard System V ABI, signature `int rfbrr(int n)` (`n` in `edi` and output in `eax`).

```
31 c0 57 5e d1 ee 31 fe f3 0f bc d6 39 c2 0f 4f c2 d1 ee 75 f3 ff c0 c3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVRbb9owFH73rzii6gQil2ZAupbCXvY67XEPpUOO4yRug53ZTkup@tvZsZNApT0UKdK5fuc7F5NRUx05qxSMjveZsAbS@QMhS0AZdCvdl6sXiZbK2sbcxjFTOS9VXUTGUvbE96yisuQRU7v4b8uNFUqaOLlK00UaI0qICGGP8r2hJV8lXyzNVoYpzXNu2AVqoVWNqyqp2UGRaR05IVReVBAWvC7SOSGGM4cPkeV7SwB/Za0yWoN2kQ5BSNspYyfJCZrMq3kGmokAJLpBxzwXQGUOqrVNa3sb3ROfd@thl8BqTjU4s9P3ysuBN/QRJbewc9ncCHgRtoKxzkW41qiu15BM4I@3THx805oKUOsU1YALW3aUEMCbTaWdHEDiPQ7ko9uTcG7XwPJUe@BjkDCroMCoWuFKTLdBVcCBa2V8y5rbVkuwFbUwhaTPRCR0W8CWMSkBo@CFQ67cBDnPwSpUgCIs8mYVZ08u2lYc8Aa0JdutH922bobpWU1FLWTpSwNTrXRzRhyedwO1B4Ym1IKPLezo3vHFIXu26O6z@jWwXdPnnAzquew3k582YypRuN1oUVYWste@0fN4vdoHi6LrHy@3rkEq6SgHvtfIhzzKA5w7HGr0k8TS0w5OSHaihc7jCNbDJRPSPTFygUF1m3O4MzYXKqrWhMQxlIxhJ1nEYDh4hSqEvykyCn/NMH9vuZb/XfeSECfsqJDjZyXyCbz1XHA9eABbRg039w@wgrckgK8BzAKYB7AIIMUx4PftBi3JbHY9u8aAm5t0sZin74FH8XvCdyAx3YgDV8X4DDqBeDBiNcfEhbvj89zE6gpHe@fTUZhOB2oDPeFQP3AUD@ei7oePEwOGZgd8/3g05hfjzahzXuaTW7jMNxu5GQUIG7hUjHeh72RYh9vV1ZK8E1yLHzUhn/zZfLqUKEadqOwxb/Eswx8Q/kRivO7jj/8A)

### Explanation

Uses [@Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)'s `n ^ (n >> 1)` trick to reduce the problem to getting the longest string of zeros in the number plus one, then finds this by shifting through the number while it is nonzero and running `tzcnt` over it to count the number of trailing zeros.

```
rfbrr:
    ; clear eax
    xor eax, eax

    ; get m in esi with (rdi->rsi >> 1) ^ (rdi)
    push rdi
    pop rsi ; n in esi
    shr esi, 1 ; n >> 1 in esi
    xor esi, edi ; m in esi

    ; search for longest run of zeros and return that + 1
    ; m is at least 1 so we dont need to do a loop check at the start
__rfbrr_lp:
    ; trailing zero count into edx
    tzcnt edx, esi

    ; max of eax and edx into eax
    cmp edx, eax
    cmovg eax, edx

    ; shift m right by 1
    shr esi, 1
    
    ; if m is still nonzero, loop.
    jnz __rfbrr_lp

    ; return eax+1
    inc eax
    ret
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `GG`, 20 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 2.5 bytes

```
bøe
```

`GG` everyone!

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9R0ciLCIiLCJiw7hlIiwiIiwiOTk2NTU0NiJd)

```
bøe­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‏​⁢⁠⁢‌⁤​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌­
b    # ‎⁡Convert number to binary.
 øe  # ‎⁢Perform run length encoding on the binary number.
‎⁣
# ‎⁤G flag takes the maximum value of the list (which is the longest run).
# ‎⁢⁡Another G flag (because the run length encoding also has the digit that is part of the longest run) takes the maximum value of that list (guaranteed to be the run length).
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 44 bytes

```javascript
f=(x,i=0)=>x&1?f(~x):x&&(t=f(x/2,++i))>i?t:i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcxBCoMwEEDRvQcJM6itaao2QvQsokamiJEayqx69bTbMtvH5z/H93hOLzpiuYd5Sck74IJcha5npQcPH8aOlYLoPPD1VuQ5IfY0xI7SFPYzbMtlCyt4aBCzf9GSHtbIzJjWtFq6EGubur7La/WT9AU)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 50 bytes

```javascript
f=x=>x&1?f(~x):x&&Math.max(f(x/2),Math.log2(x&-x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zbbC1q5CzdA@TaOuQtOqQk3NN7EkQy83sUIjTaNC30hTB8zPyU830qhQ063Q1PyfnJ9XnJ@TChIDqjHT1ORCFTHEFLKwNMZUZmxsbmxuiCmOIWJpaWZqagIy9T8A)

Equally treat 0 and 1

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `G`, 3 bytes

```
bġl
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJHIiwiIiwiYsShbCIsIiIsIjEzMzczNzEiLCIzLjQuMiJd)

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 12 bytes

```
/↥⊕⧻⊛\+°\≠.⋯
```

[Try it in the pad!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__U29sdXRpb24g4oaQIC_ihqXiipXip7viiptcK8KwXOKJoC7ii68KWzZfMgogMTZfNAogODkzXzUKIDEzMzczNzFfNgogMV8xCiA5OTY1NTQ2XzddCuKJoSjiip_iioPiiqIvKD1Tb2x1dGlvbikpCg==)